# Word similar to "farewell" but with negative connotation

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that is similar to the meaning of *farewell* or *goodbye* except that it has a negative connotation.

I find it hard to choose an appropriate word when I close communications with a person or organization that has affronted me when I really do not wish them to fare well.

Comment: Voting to close on the grounds that there can be any number of answers ranging from appropriate intonation to "Get lost and don't come back!" or fruitier. Effectively it's an invitation to offer up insults.

Comment: _[Hasta La Vista, Baby!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_7vVOnpyJY)_

Comment: @Fumble: Except the OP is specifically asking if there is a _single word_ that acts as a counterpart to _farewell_. I don't think there is, but it is an interesting question.

Comment: @Callithumpian: I recognise your point, but surely any feasible candidate must of necessity be restricted by all manner of context. For example, you might get away with "We must talk again in the next life, if not before" in some contexts, or "Please respect my privacy in future" in others.

Comment: There's also *have a nice life*.

Comment: @Callithumpian - [Possible responses](https://www.google.com/search?q=possible+responses&espv=2&biw=1024&bih=653&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU_qe_tI_LAhVDPiYKHehgC7wQ_AUIBigB): Yes/No. Or what? Go away. Please come back later. (or...)

Comment: Cool and polite, or blunt and earthy? Does it have to be a single word? And is it for your departure or his/theirs? Or just an end to all communication? Any specific kind of relationship that is ending?

Comment: @Beta this was specifically in regards to a company losing a customer. It was also a permanent termination of all communication and affirmation that there was no longer any opportunity to rectify the situation.

Comment: I know this comment is off-topic but ... hopefully the OP (in 2011!)  resisted the temptation to be rude & didn't burn any bridges.

Comment: @k1eran i can't remember the specifics anymore, but it was the company that burned bridges and my final letter informed them of their permanent loss of revenue from me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Good riddance.
I'm done with you.  (If you are. :-) )

For that matter, if this is in writing, "goodbye" may do what you want.  It's pretty rare to close email or a letter that way, so this suggests closure.  If you're speaking orally, then as drm65 says you can use tone of voice to convey your dissatisfaction.

Comment: I had thought about that in regards to Goodbye for closing letters/emails but wasn't sure since it still has the "good" part.

Answer (score 4):

It is easy to *say* "good-bye" as if you meant "good riddance!"  Try it!

*Good-bye* doesn't necessarily mean *I wish you well* anymore.

Comment: Even "I wish you well" said with the right intonation can sound negative.

Comment: _Bad-bye_ doesn't appear to appear in many dictionaries.

Comment: *You get nothing! You lose!* [*GOOD DAY, SIR!*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5QGkOGZubQ)

Answer (score 4):

As fumblefingers mentions, the answer to the question is contextual.

Nevertheless, phrases I've used in the past to point out that I am not in favour of whatever misstep the recipient of my missive has allowed themselves:

Disappointed,
MSS

Affronted,
MSS

Disapprovingly,
MSS

Disparagingly,
MSS

et ad nauseam...

Comment: Out of this group of nice choices, I think "Disappointed" would be my choice to use, if only because the others carry a heavier sense of the writer blaming the recepient.  Of course this IS the writer's point, but it might hit the recepient harder if they don't have a reason to fire back because they are feeling attacked.  They are simply left (hopefully) with the feeling that they are a miserable human being.  The rest can really be eloquently described before the golden closing term you are looking for.

Comment: +1 @Rachel : good point on the "attack" aspect of terms such as "disapprovingly". In the cases I use such language, I usually am aiming to elicit some form of response (does not always work, of course, but often...) "Disappointed" is more fire-and-forget ("I'm done with this"). Again, context is the key...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by MSS? Or is that your initials there?

Comment: Initials - yes looks like plural of MS (for Manuscripts)...

Comment: @MSS, I agree 100% - needless to say, I think all of us at one point want to throw out the most fabulous go-to of all, which I bit my tongue not to add to the list because it is hardly ladylike speech: "'F-off' and die you miserable 'POS', I hope you rot in hell - Rachel" :)

Comment: @MartinS.Stoller I just re-read the question, and realize that your answer was possibly the best. OP asked for the closing of a communication. That definitely implies a missive of some sort, whether IM, email or physical postal mail. Your suggestions are quite appropriate, as OP wants to close communications with a "person or organization", which requires some degree of formality. Up vote, or better yet, +1!

Answer (score 0):

How about "it's over," or "we're done," or "hasta la vista"?

Comment: Or the most often used term in Britain for this "sod off"